# Rancher, scaling services on the same host

Tags: docker, host, rancher

We use rancher and we have a service in a docker container that uses specific ports (8080, 2480, 2424, 2434).

We have only one host and we would like to scale the service (in such a way we can have multiple replicas of the service on the same host), but we encounter a problem. The scaling is not possible and the following error message appears:

```
Allocation failed: No healthy hosts meet the resource constraints: [8080:8080/tcp, 2480:2480/tcp, 2424:2424/tcp, 2434:2434/tcp portReservation, instanceReservation: 1]
```

Is it possible to solve this issue without increasing the number of hosts? Or, with rancher, is it not possible to have a number of service's replicas greater than the number of hosts if the service uses a specific port?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Rancher specifically; a given [ip:]port can only be bound to one container on the host.

If you want to have more than one then you need multiple IPs, multiple ports, or a single load balancer container that listens on the port and sends requests to many target containers that don't listen on a host port themselves.